# Integer gets converted to string when passed into jinja template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am trying to make a news aggregator app in GAE where I am trying to implement a rudimentary form of pagination since I couldn't understand the documentation on `cursor()`.

```
class Display(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page_no):
        is_this_last = False
        list_to_be_displayed_here = feedlist[(int(page_no)-1)*5:int(page_no)*5]
        try:
            is_last = feedlist[page_no*5]
        except:
            is_this_last = True
        self.response.write(render_str('/display.html', page_no=page_no, feedlist=list_to_be_displayed_here, is_this_last=is_this_last))
```

`feedlist` is a global list that contains the rss feeds I captured from Google News. I'm trying to get 10 feeds and display them 5 in a page.
`page_no` is an integer (the function that calls the above function hardcodes it as an integer).

This is `display.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    {% for feed in feedlist %}
        <p>{{ feed.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% set page_no = page_no + 1 %}
    {% if not is_this_last %}
        <a href="/page_no/display">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Since `page_no` is an integer, there shouldn't be a problem with the increment. But I'm getting an error saying that `str` and `int` objects can't be added.

Edit: I used the `int()` filter on page_no like so:

```
{% set page_no = int(page_no) + 1 %}
```

This is the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
response = self._internal_error(e)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
INFO     2016-08-09 23:26:39,196 module.py:787] default: "GET /1/display HTTP/1.1" 500 -
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\7c\NewsAggregatorGAE\news.py", line 93, in get
self.response.write(render_str('/display.html', page_no=page_no, feedlist=list_to_be_displayed_here, is_this_last=is_this_last))
File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\7c\NewsAggregatorGAE\news.py", line 38, in render_str
return t.render(params)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 894, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\7c\NewsAggregatorGAE\templates\display.html", line 6, in top-level template code
{% set page_no = int(page_no) + 1 %}
UndefinedError: 'int' is undefined
```

Comment: post the full traceback.. try {% set page_no = int(page_no) + 1 %}

Comment: Now I get `int is undefined`

Comment: int is a filter I believe. So try `{% set page_no = page_no|int + 1 %}`

Comment: when you write the response, you use the string version. Either wrap it in int() there or create a new variable that is an int you use in both places

Comment: and convert it to int before you send it

Comment: `page_no|int` worked. Thank you.